# Google Analytics Terminate Session after Conversion

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce, custom-dimensions

I've an e-commerce website implemented Google Analytics(UA) with the help of Google Tag Manager to track the sales and conversion. I'm using enhanced e-commerce and custom dimensions to get insights of the user's interaction and try to link them up with the conversion. For the custom dimensions, I've set the scope to session because I just need to know the last interaction of the user whether they have made a purchase or not.

Imagine I'm selling generic iPhone cases, user will choose the iPhone generations, followed by the model and finally colour. All these will be tracked in custom dimension before they make a purchase. All is good since I can link back the transaction id with the user's choices, or I could see how many drop-off for a particular iphone model.

My problem is after a user made a purchase, and decided to browse the site again by re-selecting the model, this will override the previous custom dimension values belong to that particular session and transaction.

If there a way to restart the session after a purchase has been made? Or I'm doing something wrong here where the scope of the custom dimension is set wrongly? If I set to product scope level, will by custom dimension be able to display even without any transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom dimension hit level. In this case you can query the values of that dimension that has a session with the requirements you want and check if it contains any of the values you are monitoring.

Comment: For a hit level, which data it would display in the check-out behaviour on each of the checkout step? Would it be showing duplicate data for a particular session?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your order of events is: customer selects options, customer adds fully-specified item to cart, customer checks out, then with Enhanced Ecommerce in GA I would use product-scope custom dimensions.

You will be able to combine your custom data with the fields in the Shopping Behavior tab of the Conversions > Ecommerce > Product Performance report (one at a time in that report, or all at once in a Flat Table type Custom Report), and see both purchases and abandonments. This should give more detail than you get now - for example, if a user added 2 items to their cart in a session you would see both of them, instead of only the second.

Starting a new session after a transaction is likely possible, but more complicated and with potential side effects.

Comment: I do have custom dimension that might not relate to the product which I need to track as well in the check-out behaviour. Would there be any data in the custom dimension if there is no transaction - user did not make any purchase

Comment: If the custom dimension is associated to the session you should be able to connect it to the shopping behavior, with or without a transaction. If there is something specifically relevant to starting checkout you could send it as a Checkout Option, though those have to be associated to a specific step of checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics has the [session-control field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) to restart sessions; you can set it in the "fields to set" section of the analytics tag.

> Used to control the session duration. A value of 'start' forces a new
> session to start with this hit and 'end' forces the current session to
> end with this hit. All other values are ignored.

Comment: This means I need additional tag to trigger when there's a new transaction?

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this even though I went looking for such a thing. @CalebC I think you would want to either combine this with your transaction hit or send it via an event after the transaction has been sent (and confirmation PV, etc), so that any further actions by the visitor will be in the new session.